# How to add class on click and remove that class if siblings have that class. Then scroll to the clicked element

Tags: jquery, css, sass

I'm having three sections in a form, all are collapsed.
The idea is that when you click on one of them, it opens up and it shows it's content. Then you scroll to the clicked element.
If one of them is already open, then the opened one has to close.

So currently I have this code and it works quite well:

```
$('.form__step__wrapper').click(function(){
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('open');
  $(this).addClass('open');
  $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
    scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
  }, 200);
});
```

The only problem with this code is: when you click on an item which is **under** an opened item, it doesn't scroll to that top, but somewhere in the middle. 
If I remove the function:

```
$(this).siblings().removeClass('open');
```

It works like it should and it scrolls smoothly to the correct position. But then the other section stays "open" when it should collapse again.

I think it has something to do with jQuery removing the class from the opened section, which results in a different body height, so the position of the section where you want to scroll to, changes.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The feature you are trying to implement is called accordion or collapse.

Comment: Do you have any transitions applied to the elements that are toggling visibility that might be affecting the document height by the time the scroll has been invoked?

Comment: @Cue Yes I have.

Comment: @ThomasTromp can you demonstrate this in your code examples? It’s likely you’ll need an event listener to wait for transitions to end before triggering scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method `closest` or `parent` of Jquery. To use `siblings` you would have to make a loop to remove class open of each element.

```
$(this).parent().find('.form__step__wrapper.open').removeClass('open');
$(this).addClass('open');
```